# Firebug feature available in Chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, firebug

I want to convert to using Chrome from Firefox but I'm reliant on Firebug's feature to view the result of ajax requests, whether it be json, html etc.  Does anyone know if this is available in Chrome somewhere?

I've looked everywhere in Developer Tools but can't find this specific feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. Under the tab `Network` in `Chrome Developer Tools` you can see all network traffic including request and response headers and the contents of the response. You need to have Chrome Developer Tools open before you make the ajax request because it only starts tracking the network traffic when the Developer Tools are open.

If you're looking for Chrome Developer Tools itself, you can use `right click + inspect element`, `Ctrl+Shift+C` or my preferred `F12` :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Chrome calls it the "Developer Tools", and it's built in. Check under the "Developer" menu, or try right-clicking the page and selecting "Inspect Element".